# How do you make a REST API call to Marketo using ONLY Javascript?

Tags: javascript, marketo

We are trying to read value of Marketo tracking cookie to help prefill gated asset forms on our website.

[This link](http://developers.marketo.com/blog/get-a-visitors-cookie-id-and-then-query-associated-lead-data/) explains, first, how to read the value of the cookie using Javascript (simple enough):

```
//Function to read value of a cookie
function readCookie(name) {
    var cookiename = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(cookiename) == 0) return c.substring(cookiename.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

//Call readCookie function to get value of user's Marketo cookie
var value = readCookie('_mkto_trk');
```

And then it explains how to take the value of the cookie and make the call to Marketo using REST API via Ruby:

```
#NOTE: The _mkto_trk cookie value includes an ampersand and needs to be URL encoded to '%26' in order to be properly accepted by the Marketo endpoint.  

require 'rest_client'
require 'json'

#Build request URL
#Replace AAA-BBB-CCC with your Marketo instance
marketo_instance = "https://AAA-BBB-CCC.mktorest.com"
endpoint = "/rest/v1/leads.json"
#Replace with your access token
auth_token =  "?access_token=" + "cde42eff-aca0-48cf-a1ac-576ffec65a84:ab"
#Replace with filter type and values
filter_type_and_values = "&filterType=cookies&filterValues=id:AAA-BBB-CCC%26token:_mch-marketo.com-1418418733122-51548&fields=cookies,email"
request_url = marketo_instance + endpoint + auth_token + filter_type_and_values

#Make request
response = RestClient.get request_url

#Returns Marketo API response
puts response
```

We don't use Ruby (we use Sitecore CMS).  So is there a way to take the value of the cookie, build the Marketo API URL and then make the REST API call to Marketo using only Javascript?

Comment: `jQuery.ajax` (or other library)

Comment: Or the `axios` lib: https://github.com/axios/axios

Comment: by making an AJAX request, you can use native JS syntax or use one of the many wrapper libraries, including the ones mentioned above, which usually make the syntax easier. This is assuming that the endpoint accepts CORS requests.

Comment: @maple note that every single browser supports the `fetch` API, no need for jQuery in 2023 (barring the fact that unless there are auth tokens or public api keys, you should never do this of course)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, **you should NOT access the REST API via client side javascript**. (If you talk about server side javascript, node.js, that is another case).

First of all, while technically it might be possible to make API calls from client side javascript by using ajax requests, **you would have to expose your secret API keys** (*Client Id* and *Client Secret*. That means that anybody could have read/write access to your precious data, what you definitely don't want.

Second, as ajax calls are subject to [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) (CORS) mechanism it would only work from the client side if you would run these requests from the host of your REST API Endpoint (e.g.: https://123-ABC-456.mktorest.com).

Comment: Appreciate the knowledge. From what I've seen, Marketo doesn't allow for CORS anyway.  So am I correct that really the only feasible/safe option is to make the Marketo API call using whatever server-side language our site uses (we use the Sitecore CMS so I believe it's .NET)?

Comment: Yes, the only safe option is to use the REST API from server side. [Marketo has a Github account](https://github.com/Marketo/REST-Sample-Code) with SDKs available in some languages. Unfortunately there is no .NET SDK yet, but I guess you could use one of the existing ones as a sample to make up your .NET version.